# Trying to only use HTML to make a sh script on PC run when a button is clicked

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to make it where my code runs a sh script on my PC when the button is clicked. Here's what I have now:

The button:

```
<a href="exec.php">Run the Program</a>
```

The php code:

```
<html><body>
<?
if(isset($_POST["submit"]))) {exec("sh launcher.sh");}
?>
</body></html>
```

But when I click the button, all it does is download the file. How can I make it where it executes rather than download the file?

Comment: A link (`<a>` tag) will not issue a `POST` request

Comment: I hate to be critical but you should post well formatted read able HTML. There is so much missing it can't even be edited to look right. As a side note you should almost never use inline style's.

Comment: Short PHP tags should not be used. You should put your (frankly excessive) style CSS into a class attribute and call the class file.

Comment: What will then? @PatrickQ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your method won't work because, as Patrick Q mentioned in the comments, an `a href` doesn't post anything; it's just a link. Posting data is typically done via a `form` element or JavaScript. However, your browser still shouldn't download the PHP; this indicates that PHP isn't executing your script at all. Try using long PHP tags:

```
<html><body>
<?php
if(isset($_POST["submit"]))) {exec("sh launcher.sh");}
?>
</body></html>
```

From [the PHP docs/forum](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php):

```
<?php ?> // standard tags
<? ?> // short tags, need short_open_tag enabled in php.ini
```

Comment: I'll try this later - might I add that I'm using a Raspberry Pi running Raspbian, with the browser "Epiphany Browser".

Comment: @dylan You may :P If you got PHP and your server set up properly, it shouldn't make a difference whether it's a Pi, laptop, rack server, whatever.

Comment: I'm just trying to run the file locally, like the webpage is on my Pi as an HTML document and I've got a separate PHP document I'm trying to use to execute it.

Comment: So what would I use instead of the `<a>` tag? @JDo

Comment: So if I use `<form>` instead, will I be able to use the styling I had on my original button?

Comment: @dylan Maybe you should find a tutorial that explains - from the ground up - how HTML, CSS, JavaScript and PHP interact to create web content. I'm not trying to be condescending but it's not the point of your question and the comment section is not the right place for Q&A regarding basic web development. The short answer to your question is "yes"; there's nothing about a `form` element that limits your options in terms of styling.

Comment: @dylan Is PHP runnng *any* of your scripts?